# How can I connect AWS Redshift with Python Jupyter NoteBook to extract stored Data?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I want to connect AWS Redshift with Python (Jupyter Notebook), I tried using some tutorials on Youtube but I failed to connect properly. I used these codes and I am getting the error below:

```
!pip install pandas
!pip install psycopg2
!pip install psycopg2-binary
!pip install sqlalchemy

import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text

sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name;"

redshift_endpoint = 'db_name-3d15f6e600bd37dbd0c9a.cutowxhzbeso.ap-south-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'
redshift_user = 'username'
redshift_password = 'password'
port = 8200
db_name = 'db_name'

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
engine_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s" \
% (redshift_user, redshift_password, redshift_endpoint, port, db_name)
engine = create_engine(engine_string)

df = pd.read_sql_query(text(sql), engine)
```

> **OperationalError**: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
> Is the server running on host "db_name-3d15f6e600bd37dbd0c9a.cutowxhzbeso.ap-south-1.redshift.amazonaws.com" (10.0.1.148) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 8200?
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The computer you are on is unable to connect to the database server running at that URL on port 8200. Somewhere between your computer where you are running this code and that redshift endpoint, port 8200 isn't connecting. Is that the correct port for your system? What happens if you attempt to `telnet <endpoint_url> 8200`? Does it connect?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct port for my system, but I don't know where is the fault.